# How do I write a vue popup modal for a login / register component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, modal-dialog, vuejs3, laravel-breeze

What I am trying to design is a new Login / Register modal for using with the standard Vue Login & Register scaffolding that comes with Laravel Breeze.

Exactly what I am trying to achieve is this:

Login / Register Button -> Clicked and a modal opens
The modal contains a header section where there is a "Login" tab and a "Register" tab, by default the login tab is selected. It then contains a body section that is a panel that switches between the "login.vue" file and the "register.vue" file.

It is from my understanding that I need to do the following:

1. Create a button that when clicked open the modal component.
2. Create a Vue component to house the modal code & tabs that conditionally render the login or register page.

My file structure is as follows

```
resources | js | Pages | Auth \-\> Login.vue (standard breeze code)

resources | js | Pages | Auth \-\> Register.vue (standard breeze code)

resources | js | Pages | Modal \-\> LoginRegister.vue
```

Thanks in advance, I would really appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the tabbed component (LoginRegister.vue) that switches between the login & register page was to use headless UI and create the tabs & dynamically rendered login or register component, with just importing the login.vue & register.vue, this is how I did it:

```
<template>
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-xl px-2 sm:px-0">
        <TabGroup>
            <TabList class="flex rounded-xl bg-blue-900/20 p-1 space-x-1">
                <Tab
                    as="template"
                    v-slot="{ selected }"
                >
                    <button
                        :class="[
              'w-full rounded-lg py-2.5 p-4 font-medium leading-5 text-slate-800 text-blue-700',
              'ring-white ring-opacity-60 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2',
              selected
                ? 'bg-white shadow'
                : 'text-blue-100 hover:bg-white/[0.12] hover:text-white',
            ]"
                    >
                        Login
                    </button>
                </Tab>
                <Tab
                    as="template"
                    v-slot="{ selected }"
                >
                    <button
                        :class="[
              'w-full rounded-lg py-2.5 p-4 font-medium leading-5 text-blue-700',
              'ring-white ring-opacity-60 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2',
              selected
                ? 'bg-white shadow'
                : 'text-blue-100 hover:bg-white/[0.12] hover:text-white',
            ]"
                    >
                        Register
                    </button>
                </Tab>
            </TabList>
            <TabPanels class="mt-2">
                <TabPanel class="rounded-xl bg-white p-3 ring-white ring-opacity-60 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2">
                    <Login/>
                </TabPanel>
                <TabPanel class="rounded-xl bg-white p-3 ring-white ring-opacity-60 ring-offset-2 ring-offset-blue-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2">
                    <Register/>
                </TabPanel>
            </TabPanels>
        </TabGroup>
    </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import Login from "@/Pages/Auth/Login.vue";
import Register from "@/Pages/Auth/Register.vue";
import {Tab, TabGroup, TabList, TabPanel, TabPanels} from '@headlessui/vue'
</script>
```

I Then was able to use a modal component I found, which is the following code:

```
<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted, onUnmounted, watch } from 'vue';
import LoginRegister from "@/Pages/Auth/LoginRegister.vue";

const props = defineProps({
    show: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    maxWidth: {
        type: String,
        default: '2xl',
    },
    closeable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    },
});

const emit = defineEmits(['close']);

watch(() => props.show, () => {
    if (props.show) {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
        document.body.style.overflow = null;
    }
});

const close = () => {
    if (props.closeable) {
        emit('close');
    }
};

const closeOnEscape = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Escape' && props.show) {
        close();
    }
};

onMounted(() => document.addEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscape));

onUnmounted(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeOnEscape);
    document.body.style.overflow = null;
});

const maxWidthClass = computed(() => {
    return {
        'sm': 'sm:max-w-sm',
        'md': 'sm:max-w-md',
        'lg': 'sm:max-w-lg',
        'xl': 'sm:max-w-xl',
        '2xl': 'sm:max-w-2xl',
    }[props.maxWidth];
});
</script>

<template>
    <teleport to="body">
        <transition leave-active-class="duration-200">
            <div v-show="show" class="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto px-4 py-6 sm:px-0 z-50" scroll-region>
                <transition
                    enter-active-class="ease-out duration-300"
                    enter-from-class="opacity-0"
                    enter-to-class="opacity-100"
                    leave-active-class="ease-in duration-200"
                    leave-from-class="opacity-100"
                    leave-to-class="opacity-0"
                >
                    <div v-show="show" class="fixed inset-0 transform transition-all" @click="close">
                        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75" />
                    </div>
                </transition>

                <transition
                    enter-active-class="ease-out duration-300"
                    enter-from-class="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                    enter-to-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    leave-active-class="ease-in duration-200"
                    leave-from-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
                    leave-to-class="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
                >
                    <div v-show="show" class="mb-6 bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full sm:mx-auto" :class="maxWidthClass">
                        <div v-if="show">
                           <LoginRegister />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </transition>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </teleport>
</template>
```